# Methods addDiagramListener and removeDiagramListener is never getting called in gojs

Tags: javascript, typescript, diagram, gojs

Hope you all are doing well!!
I'm facing some issues in calling the Diagram event. Here I'm posting a few use-cases which didn't work for me and what's worked.

CASE I) Did not work :
Calling addDiagramListener and removeDiagramListener one after other for the same function reference "setLayout" didn't work. None of them or both addDiagramListener or removeDiagramListener got fired.

```
export class DiagramListenerTestClass {
  execute(context: any): any {
    let diagram = context.diagram;
    diagram.layout = new go.ForceDirectedLayout;
    diagram.addDiagramListener("LayoutCompleted", setLayout);
    diagram.removeDiagramListener("LayoutCompleted", setLayout);
 }
}

// Define outside the class
var setLayout = function (event) {
  event.diagram.layout = new go.Layout();
  console.log("Method called!!");
}
```

CASE II) Worked :
Calling removeDiagramListener after some setTimeout, fired both addDiagramListener and removeDiagramListener.

```
export class DiagramListenerTestClass {
  execute(context: any): any {
    let diagram = context.diagram;
    diagram.layout = new go.ForceDirectedLayout;
    diagram.addDiagramListener("LayoutCompleted", setLayout);
    setTimeout(() => { diagram.removeDiagramListener("LayoutCompleted", setLayout) }, 100);
 }
}
// Define outside the class
var setLayout = function (event) {
  event.diagram.layout = new go.Layout();
  console.log("Method called!!");
}
```

Note: I'm not sure about the reason why case II worked and not CASE I. What I assume for the successful execution of CASE II is that: "the calls for addDiagramListener and removeDiagramListener was so quick that before addDiagramListener 'setLayout' function gets called, the listener gets removed by 'removeDiagramListener' ".So to get's the function successfully executed, I called 'removeDiagramListener' with some setTimeout of 100ms.

Please do let me correct if there's something not correct.
Your suggestions would be very helpful and appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `diagram.layout = new go.ForceDirectedLayout;` should probably be `diagram.layout = new go.ForceDirectedLayout();`

Comment: @SimonSarris  Though new go.ForceDirectedLayout and new go.ForceDirectedLayout() serves the same purpose. But yes go.ForceDirectedLayout() is more clear and familiar. Thanks for bringing this to notice.
Could you please suggest anything on the above issue mentioned? Thanks!!